# How to make a logical implementation of the below php code?

Tags: php, arrays, logic

I need an out put like this.Can you please help me to sort this out?

```
a-1,2,4 
b-3
```

for the following code:

```
<?php
    $paytype = array('a','a','b','a');
    $payno= array(1,2,3,4);

    for($i=0;$i<count($paynum);$i++){
        $paytypes = $paytype[$i];
        $paynum = $payno[$i];

    }
?>
```

Please Help

Answer (score 2):

Just use [array_unique](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-unique.php), [array_map](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-map.php) and [array_keys](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-keys.php) like this:

```
<?php
$paytype = array('a','a','b','a');
$payno= array(1,2,3,4);

$uniqArr = array_unique($paytype);  //Get all the unique value from array

foreach ($uniqArr as $value) {
    echo $value . "-" . implode(",",array_map("matchVal",array_keys($paytype,$value)))."<br/>"; 
}

function matchVal($x) {
    global $payno;
    return $payno[$x];
}
```

Output:

```
a-1,2,4
b-3
```

[Demo](https://eval.in/573585)

Answer (score 1):

You can try this:

```
<?php
    $paytype = array('a','a','b','a');
    $payno= array(1,2,3,4);
    $newArr = array();
    for($i=0;$i<count($paytype);$i++){
        if(!isset($newArr[$paytype[$i]])) {
            $newArr[$paytype[$i]] = $payno[$i];
        } else {
            $newArr[$paytype[$i]] = $newArr[$paytype[$i]].",".$payno[$i];
        }
    }
    print '<pre>';print_r($newArr);
?>
```

Output:

```
Array
(
    [a] => 1,2,4
    [b] => 3
)
```

Answer (score 0):

Another alternative:-

Just use a simple `foreach` loop:-

```
$paytype = ['a','a','b','a'];
$payno= [1,2,3,4];
$res = [];

foreach($paytype as $k=>$v){
  $res[$v] = empty($res[$v]) ? $payno[$k] : $res[$v].','.$payno[$k];
}

print '<pre>';print_r($res);
```

**output**:-

```
Array
(
    [a] => 1,2,4
    [b] => 3
)
```

If you want output

```
a-1,2,4 
b-3
```

then add one additional foreach at the end.

```
foreach($res as $k=>$v){
  echo "$k-$v<br>";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

just use this code.

```
$paytype = array('a','a','b','a');
    $payno= array(1,2,3,4);

    $result = array();
    for($i=0;$i<count($paytype);$i++){
        $result[$paytype[$i]][] = $payno[$i];
    }

    $var = '';
    foreach($result as $k => $v)
    {
        $var .= "{$k} - ". implode(",", $v) . "<br />";
    }


    print_r($var);
```

Result :

```
a - 1,2,4
b - 3
```